# tomcat and apache http together

Tags: apache, tomcat6, ubuntu-11.10

can I install apache tomcat 6 and apache http web server on the same machine (Ubuntu 11.10) without problems ?

tomcat to serve GeoServer

apache web serve to serve static files

Comment: Yes, but this question is better for serverfault.com as it has more to do with server management and less with programming.

Answer (score 0):

Install (bind) each either on separate IPs, or same IPs but different ports.

In the last case, you can have Apache running on port 80 and ProxyPass URLs to Tomcat running on port 8080. That way Apache becomes the front-end.

Comment: Thank you. So, i do not have to configure anything ? just install Apache on port 80 ant tomcat on port 8080 ?

Comment: @Shadin, yes (more or less). But you'll still need to add a few ProxyPass directives if you want Apache to be the front end.